# C# - How do I iterate all the rows in Excel._Worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-interop

I am looking to programmatically pull data from an Excel worksheet and insert it into a database table.

How do I determine the number of columns and rows in a worksheet or otherwise iterate the rows?

I have

```
Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

I tried `worksheet.Range.Rows.Count`

which tosses up

> Indexed property 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Range' has
>   non-optional arguments which must be provided

What needs to be done?

Comment: What version of excel are you working with?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...

public void IterateRows(Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    //Get the used Range
    Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
    
    //Iterate the rows in the used range
    foreach(Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
    {
        //Do something with the row.
    
        //Ex. Iterate through the row's data and put in a string array
        String[] rowData = new String[row.Columns.Count];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < row.Columns.Count; i++)
            rowData[i] =Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1, i + 1].Value2);
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs just great for me! I'm using it to extract rows with missing fields to an error log.

Comment: Should be String[] rowData = new String[row.Columns.Count];

Comment: Should that foreach line be foreach(Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows) ?

Comment: Note that this method may be too slow for a lot of uses, converting the entire range to an object array prior to iterating will speed things up.

Comment: Got: 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumerator' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib...' when I try to iterate over the usedRange.Rows

Answer (score 18):

I presume you are actually looking for the last used row.  In that case you need to write it like this:

```
Range UsedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
int lastUsedRow = UsedRange.Row + UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
```